# How is the concept of $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ extended to $\Bbb N/2\Bbb N$? Is $\Bbb N/2\Bbb N$ ambiguous?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, monoid, quotient-group

> How is the concept of $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ extended to $\Bbb N/2\Bbb N$?  Is $\Bbb N/2\Bbb N$ ambiguous?

I believe $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ to be unambiguous terminology for cosets of the form $\{0,1\}+2\Bbb Z$ which is a representation of the cyclic abelian group $C_2$ having 2 elements and satisfying

$0+0=0, \\0+1=1, \\1+1=0.$

The difference between the group and the monoid quotient arises because in the case of $\Bbb N$, the set of additive transformations between two elements of the monoid, is **NOT** the monoid $\Bbb N$, it is the group $\Bbb Z$.

Therefore there are two ways to extend this idea to a quotient on the monoid $\Bbb N$.

Way one, which seems most natural to me is to define equivalence classes using the GROUP $\Bbb Z=\Bbb N-\Bbb N$ as follows: $x\sim y\iff\exists i\in\Bbb Z:x-y=2i$

Then we have $\Bbb N/2\Bbb N\cong\{0,1\}+2\Bbb N$ which is, heretofore, my meaning of a monoid quotient.  But, is this a normal interpretation of $\Bbb N/2\Bbb N$?

---

Way two, if one was minded to do so, would be to argue the claim that $1+3\neq0$ because there does not exist $-4\in\Bbb N:4-4=0$.  Then we would have, well, something relatively degenerate but off the top of my head we'd require left- and right- equality, and equality would be a kind of *equivalent mod 2 and greater than*, or *equivalent mod 2 and less than*.

> Is the first case not the accepted meaning of a monoid quotient?

Here is the problem I have:  Whenever I do precisely the same as **way one** above, but in a *multiplicative* monoid, as I do [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3453860/) I receive the objection analogous to the statement that $\Bbb N/2\Bbb N\neq\{0,1\}+2\Bbb N$ in this additive monoid.  So I need to clear up whether it is I using unclear or just plain wrong terminology.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you real question is :let $M$ be a commutative monoid, written additively, and let $N$ be a submonoid. How to define properly a quotient monoid $M/N$ ?

First, we need a good equivalence relation on $M$ (and this is why you got into trouble. You didn't have the right one). Say that $m\sim_N m'$ if there 
exists $n,n'\in N$ such that $m+n=m'+n'$.

This is indeed an equivalence relation on $M$, because we have a commutative monoid $M$, and $N$ is a submonoid (I leave you the details).

Call $M/N$ the quotient set. Notice that if $m_1\sim_N m'_1$ and $m_2\sim_N m'_2$, then $m_1+m'_1\sim_N m_2+m'_2$ (once again because we have a commutative monoid and $N$ is a submonoid), so you get a law on $M/N$ defined by $\overline{m}_1+\overline{m}_2=\overline{m_1+m_2}$, which makes $M/N$ a monoid, such that the canonical map $M\to M/N$ is a morphism of monoid.

If you apply all of this to $M=\mathbb{N}$ and $N=2\mathbb{N}$, you will get what you want.

Comment: I'm struggling a bit with your notation but I'll work through it. But can I ask, does $\Bbb N/2\Bbb N$ in the sense you define have more than two elements?

Comment: @samerivertwice it has two elements, because it corresponds to the congruence in my answer and this congruence has precisely two equivalence classes.

Comment: I get you now.  This is the same quotient as **way one** above, the way I've been doing it.  You've avoided using $\Bbb Z$ to define it by using two pairs of elements from $\Bbb N$.

Comment: The advantage of your definition here which seems identical *in effect* to **way one** in the question, seems to be that it introduces neither subtraction nor $\Bbb Z$.  Is this what you mean by I *don't have the right equivalence relation* - that way one above relies upon the existence of an inverse and the monoid being the subalgebra of a group whereas your definition here makes no mention of either?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean. This is really the natural way to proceed. Think about you define $\mathbb{Z}$ from $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Ok thanks. The benefits of defining it this way are clear in that it's a method that generalises to a monoid which is not necessarily a subalgebra of a group.

Answer (score 4):

In the field of universal algebra there are [congruences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_relation) and that is (I think) what you are looking for. A congruence relation is basically an equivalence relation that takes into account the algebraic structure. Congruence relations correspond bijectively to quotient algebraic structures. Notion of a congruence can be thought of as a generalization of notions of a normal subgroup of a group and two-sided ideal of a ring etc. For instance consider a group $G$ and its normal subgroup $N$. Then

$$x\equiv y \mbox{ iff }xy^{-1}\in N$$

is a congruence relation and every congruence relation on $G$ is of this form (i.e. it comes from a unique normal subgroup of $G$).

Let $\left(\mathbb{N},+,0\right)$ be a monoid. Consider a congruence relation $\equiv$ on this monoid such that one of the equivalence classes of $\equiv$ is precisely the set of even numbers $2\mathbb{N}$. Then your question can be rigorously stated as follows:

> Is the congruence $\equiv$ unique?

The answer is yes. Pick two odd natural numbers $a, b\in \mathbb{N}\setminus 2\mathbb{N}$. Without loss of generality $a <b$. Then $b- a$ is even. Hence $b-a \equiv 0$. Now since $\equiv$ is a congruence, we derive that 
$$a + (b-a) \equiv a+0$$
Thus $a\equiv b$ and hence all odd numbers are equivalent. So $\equiv$ has only two equivalence classes $2\mathbb{N}$ and $1+2\mathbb{N}$.

**Remark.**
You can check that the equivalence relation $\equiv$ with equivalence classes $2\mathbb{N}$ and $1+2\mathbb{N}$ is a congruence for $\left(\mathbb{N},+,0\right)$.

Comment: Thanks. I get this, but is this a different thing to the monoid quotient then?  Does that look radically different to this?

Comment: Actually congruence relations on a given algebra $A$ correspond bijectively to the quotient algebras of $A$. If $A$ is an algebra and $\equiv$ is a congruence, then $A/_{\equiv}$ is an algebra that is a quotient of $A$ and every quotient algebra of $A$ arises in this way.

Comment: I think the point is that in general quotients are by compatible equivalence relations/congruences: the "kernel" is not in general given by a sub-thing, or even a normal sub-thing - I think the OP doesn't really like that.

Comment: @ancientmathematician that is precisely my point. I don't know what are OP's feelings about it :), but you may be right.

Comment: @ancientmathematician am I right in thinking you mean; *those who want to argue **way two** in the question don't like that*?

Comment: @samerivertwice. No, I think both the ways in the question are misleading. They are trying to transfer the groups/rings/vector space story to structures where the kernel has nothing to do with sub-structures.

Comment: @ancientmathematician (+1) you're remark is very reasonable.